# Elegant design of simulating a read-only object

Tags: c#, oop, mocking

I am currently developing an `GUI` to an embedded system. *(I am using GUI to descripe my app opposed to interface to avoid confusion with the progamatic meaning)*

**Context**

I have created a class which simulates the embedded system. I do all my communications through a `Connection` class I have designed which can communicate via TCP/Serial or a virtual connection between two `Connection` objects.

All this works nicely and as expected, my simulated object and `GUI` communicate via the virtual connection.

I have a `Diagnostic` packet which is sent from the `device` (real or simulated) and read by the `GUI`. This fits nicely into a class which I have called `ControllerDiagnostic`.

**Question**

My question relates to the `ControllerDiagnostic` class. On the `GUI` side all properties should be read-only *(DeSerialization is done via reflection on the  private fields directly)*. On the simulation side they clearly need to be mutable. So how do I handle this elegantly? I've considered:

- Creating a completely new class which mimics `ControllerDiagnostic` but exposes setting of the fields.
- Creating all fields in `ControllerDiagnostic` protected then inheriting into a private nested class which provides accessors to these fields within the simulation class.
- Creating an assembly with just two classes and using an `Internal` setter.
- Leave the properties as read/write and document the `GUI` should not modify them.
- Re-writing C# so I could use `friend` in the same way I can in C++.

None of these seem ideal to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could write an interface which exposes all properties of your class with getters and setters and a second interface which only exposes the getters for all your properties. Then have a single class implement both interfaces and use the getter-only interface in the GUI.

In code that could look somewhat like this:

```
public interface IReadWrite
{
    string SomeString { get; set; }
}

public interface IReadOnly
{
    string SomeString { get; }
}

public class TestClass : IReadWrite, IReadOnly
{
    public string SomeString { get; set; }
}
```